# What command is the most effective for listing processes?

Tags: bash, process, kill, ps, htop

I've seen lots of developers use `ps -ef` to list processes and kill them (such as in ENCOM, devs of OS-12).

However, there is also `htop`. A friend told me that it is only a wrapper around ps and therefore that therefore there is no difference.

What's the difference between `ps` and `htop`? Is one able to list more processes? Which one is better to use?

Comment: See http://ask.xmodulo.com/view-threads-process-linux.html or similar, it is otherwise personal preference.

Comment: Usually questions that include "the best" are opinion-based by definition...

Comment: Htop isn't a wrapper, it's a separate program. They all do the same thing, but ps does it once while htop does it continuously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'ps' command only displays processes.  `htop` by default shows each thread as a separate process. Which implies 'htop' will always show more items than 'ps'.

We can show per-thread statistics with the 'ps' command as well.

for ex:

```
ps -Lf | grep xyz.sh
```

**Which one to use ?**

- If you are looking for threads status of a single process - `htop`
- If you are calculating CPU, memory usage - `ps`

  One can get the info from both the commands. But default view makes the difference here. For ex: To check the memory used by a process, One should look at the process level, since threads share memory. So, `ps` is preferable. But, we can configure `htop` as well.

To turn off the display of threads for `htop`, press H, or use the "Setup / Display options" menu, "Hide userland threads". This puts the following line in your ~/.htoprc or ~/.config/htop/htoprc (Recent versions do not use ~/.htoprc, but rather ~/.config/htop/htoprc):

```
hide_userland_threads=1
```